# Process status on AIX

Tags: process, aix

I want to get process status on AIX like we get it on Linux from `/proc/<PID>/stat`,
I did not find the status in `/proc/<PID>/status` file. There was some encrypted text there. Which file should I access on AIX to get status of a particular process?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of AIX `/proc/<PID>/status` should be structured as `struct pstatus` defined in `<sys/procfs.h>` include file. As far as I know, there is no standard for `/proc/<PID>/*` file structure, so all reading of `/proc` should be considered OS-specific code. Do not expect a strict one-for-one mapping for every data element you can find in Linux `/proc` in any other OS: the data may be arranged very differently, or some data elements may be completely missing.

See the IBM documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/filesreference/proc.html

For a C API, basically, read `/proc/<PID>/status` into a buffer of suitable size (or `mmap()` it), cast the buffer/mmap pointer into `(struct pstatus *)` and use it to access the data elements.

Depending on exactly what status information you're after, you may need to read other files in the same directory, using their equivalent structure types to access the data elements.

Answer (score 0):

To get information about a process, call the [`ps` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/ps.htm?lang=en). Pass the `-o` option to choose what information to output and control the format.

AIX has a [`/proc` directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/proc.htm?lang=en), but its content isn't the same as Linux (although there are similarities). There is a file `/proc/<PID>/status` for each process; it is in binary format (not encrypted), and that format is documented if you really want to use that rather than the output of `ps`.

Comment: I want to access it using any C API, is there any API for this?

Comment: @diago Yes, [`popen`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/popen.htm?lang=en) and run `ps`. I don't think AIX has a lower-level interface that doesn't require forking, unless you want to bake in the binary format of `/proc/<PID>/status` (which would only work on AIX, and could change in later versions). Use `popen` and parse the output of `ps` with a carefully chosen `-o` format.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe should be a comment - but I do not have enough 'status' to do that, sigh... - so trying to provide a starting point for an answer!

"like we get on linux..." does not not say much to an AIX person. I have tried something simple: is status 'OTHER' something you would accept as an answer.

From a Linux server I tried:

```
root@x064:[/data]cat /proc/1/status

  ▒▒/▒0▒0▒;▒
            ▒▒▒9▒E▒4▒œOTHER
root@x064:[/data]
root@x064:[/data/prj/gnu/less-481]strings /proc/1/status
OTHER
```

On AIX it looks similiar:

```
michael@x071:[/home/michael]cat /proc/1/status
  dò0ò0 ~5!(FiË3ã­ú¤ÀOTHER
michael@x071:[/home/michael]strings /proc/1/status
!(Fi
Ë3ã­ú
OTHER
```

imho - the strings !(Fi  and Ë3ã­ú are just looking like strings, but are just 'normal status that show as strings'

The commands you should look at for viewing /proc are:

```
michael@x071:[/home/michael]ls -l /usr/bin/proc*
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin            8462 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/proccred
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           23820 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procfiles
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           14852 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procflags
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           11222 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procldd
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           20884 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procmap
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin            8274 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procrun
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin            8974 Aug 06 2011  /usr/bin/procsig
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           24534 Jan 29 2015  /usr/bin/procstack
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin            8502 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procstop
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           34888 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/proctree
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin           13612 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procwait
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin            9158 Jan 12 2015  /usr/bin/procwdx
```